# Function defined as _c(text) error about expecting array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Were `_c`/`_x` some kind of Postgres 9.1 reserved word (or just a bug) ?

I defined a method named `_c`, giving no error on create, but when I try to call the method I get an unexpected error about wrong array format.

Here's how you can reproduce:

```
# create or replace function _c(text) returns
text as $$
select $1;
$$ language sql immutable;

# select _c('test');
ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information

-- This works just fine, only _c returns error
# create or replace function _cc(text) returns
text as $$
select $1;
$$ language sql immutable;

# select _cc('test');
_cc  
------
 test
(1 row)
```

Tried more "letters" and it seems `_x` has the same error.

I could reproduce this only in 9.1, on 9.4.4 the problem seems to be fixed and works as expected.

Comment: Working in `PostgreSQL 9.2.4` also !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses underscore-prefixed names to mean "an array of (original type)", e.g. `_int4` is the internal type name of an array of int4, i.e. `int4[]`.

Presumably it's getting confused by that if you also have a table named `c`.

```
test=> select _c('fred');
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "fred"
LINE 1: select _c('fred');
                  ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

test=> drop table c;
DROP TABLE

test=> select _c('fred');
  _c  
------
 fred
(1 row)
```

Comment: You are right, I did had a table "c", dropping the table solved the issue in v9.1 (using 9.4.4 in production, but was curious when I saw this on an old dev VM still using 9.1). Thanks

Comment: Creating a table "c" in 9.4.4 reveals the same issue. Should I fill a bug for this ?

Comment: @RaduMaris You can if you like. I'm not sure if it's a bug as such, more of an internal design wart. Still worth reporting on case there turns out to be an easy fix. Please *include a link to your SO question* but also fully describe the issue with a complete self contained test case script.

Answer (score 0):

Casting the arguments helps the parser figure out the correct path to take:

```
# select _c('text'::text);
  _c  
------
 text
(1 row)
```

Thanks Tom Lane for pointing that out in the postgres mailing list:

> The reason that happens is that the internal name of the array type
>   c[] is "_c", and the order of search for ambiguous function names is
>   such that a function-style cast interpretation will be selected over
>   an actual function; see
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/typeconv-func.html
>   particularly step 3.
>
> The way to get this to work as desired is to cast the argument to the
>   right type:
>
> select _c('text'::text);
>
> Then you get a match at step 2 in the resolution sequence ("exact
>   match of argument types"), so the user-defined function wins out over
>   the cast interpretation.

Here's the full post: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/16142.1443542877@sss.pgh.pa.us#16142.1443542877@sss.pgh.pa.us